# How To redirect pdf in new tab

Tags: visualforce

Kindly help me as i want to open a pdf in new tab on click button "view pdf".

VVF Page:

```
<apex:commandButton value="View As PDF" 
                    action="{!viewAsPDF}"  
                    onClick="window.open('/apex/DynamicQueryPDF?dreamMapDetails=')"/>
```

Class:

```
public PageReference viewAsPDF(){
    PageReference reRend = new PageReference('/apex/DynamicQueryPDF?dreamMapDetails='+strDreamGoalId+'&'+'clientId='+strClientId);
    return reRend;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: how can i pass id to window.open at on click

Comment: '/apex/DynamicQueryPDF?dreamMapDetails='+strDreamGoalId+'&'+'clientId='+strClientId

Comment: Why don't you try to put variables to the url string? `onClick="window.open('/apex/DynamicQueryPDF?dreamMapDetails={!strDreamGoalId}&clientId={!strClientId}')"`

Comment: What about using just a link with target="blank"? Params again as @mast0r said.